# Running a java program from my website

Tags: java, html

I have a java application which I would like to run from my website.  I have written the code to save data to the database and code to return the data (hopefully :). Do I put the java main.class right in my webpage? Do I need a servlet or applet?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean when you say, ` I would like to run from my website`. you want to trigger on on some event, like button click ?

Comment: Do you want to run the applet on the server-side or the client-side? If it's the latter, you'll need an applet, but most browsers these days disable those for security reasons.

Comment: I think you are asking how to use java as your server side for a website.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is an application container such as tomcat or jboss. With that you can write your code in a servlet which receives a http request object, fetches data from your database then sends the data back in the response object (remember that you are sending back html, not just strings)

This is the simplest way to understand how it works. A better way to structure it is to have a servlet call a EJB and/or a DAO which handles the business/data layer then have the servlet direct the user to a jsp page to handle the presentation of the data.

applets are pretty much dead.

Comment: I have a java application which I would like visitors to my website to be able to use. It does not need to run within the webpage but does need to be accessed from the website. Basically a person can enter data and it is saved to the database and then the data can be retrieved to form lists of students enrolled in certain classes and their grades. It is just a sample program.

Comment: or java web start or JNLP?